# Button inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-tablayout

Hi I am creating an application that is using a `Button` inside a `Fragment`, so when I click that `Button`, then that `Butto`n will make a Toast text, I use the `Button` click listener instead. But the problem is that my `Button` didn't response to a clicked, when I click it the `Button` response nothing so I get a stressed out with it. Here is my main problem's code :

```
test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
t_layout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
t_layout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Fragment fragment;
            String contain = tab.getText().toString();
        if(contain.equals("POWER")){
                fragment = new power_fragment();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment2, fragment);
                ft.commit();

                test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Test on",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }
                          }
                       }
                    }
               });
```

I am using a Tabitems so when I click the Tabitem of "POWER" the `Fragment` will change to power_fragment layout which contains the test `Button`. But the test `Button` can't make a Toast text even when it is clicked.

Comment: Where does the  `test` object even come from... Why do you not set the `onClickListener` in your `onCreateView` in your `Fragments`'s class?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I fixed the code, I forget to give the test object, but I dont understand how to put my onClickListener in my onCreateView if my Fragment, because that class I use is extends from Fragment even it gives me red line for findViewById, then how do I do it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

inside your fragment class

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_blood_group_requests, container, false);

    btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //make your toast here
        }
    });
   return v;
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what is view and what is the function of it in this case, then how if I want to make a toast ? Because I cant use getApplicationContext() for the context

Comment: In fragment onCreateView method works like onCreate method of an activity. We need to give a view to populate and return it. so in a view object we initialize a layout view. findViewById is a method of view which is blind in  any activity so we dont need a view object in activity. but in fragment we need view object to call findViewById. without findViewById  we cant initial any view component like button and textview. that is all i know. I dont know full architecture of android.

Comment: getApplicationContext() return full app context which we don't need most. use getContext() for context .

Answer (score 1):

You can't use findViewById inside fragment. You need to do something like this.

```
test = (Button) primaryView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
test.setOnClickListener(this);
```

// this primaryView is your container view which you returns on onCreateView;

```
return primaryView;
```

/// fragment should implement View.OnClickListener

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.test:
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `test` button in power_fragment and also write `OnClickListener` in power_fragment as you put that `test` button in power_fragment's layout

Place below code in your power_fragment

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.power_fragment, container, false);
Button test = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I dont understand how to put my onClickListener in my onCreateView if my Fragment, because that class I use is extends from Fragment even it gives me red line for findViewById, then how do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I put onClick by that way and it worked fine

```
public class fragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button myButton;

    @Override
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedinstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        myButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // implements your things
    }
}
```